# Powershell operations in method parameters

Tags: powershell, function

This code works, but I want to find the clean way to make this one line:

```
$domainUser = Get-Content "C:\Staging\domainUser.encrypted" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$ddomainUser = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($domainUser))
```

Similar to this:

```
$ddomainUser = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR(Get-Content "C:\Staging\domainUser.encrypted" | ConvertTo-SecureString))
```

Comment: `[Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', (Get-Content "C:\Staging\domainUser.encrypted" | ConvertTo-SecureString)).Password`

Comment: `[Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', (Get-Content -Path "$env:HOMEDRIVE/Staging/domainUser.encrypted" | ConvertTo-SecureString)).Password`